# How to create a SQL Stored Procedure with multiple expressions in subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an Orders table and I want to pull some columns from the Orders tables and records from one of two OrderDetails tables depending on the value of a column in the Orders table.

**Orders**

```
OrderID Pk int
OrderDetails_A_ID
OrderDate
OrderedById
```

**OrderDetails_A**

```
OrderDetails_A_ID Pk int
OrderID Fk int
Qty_A
ItemDesc_A
```

**OrderDetails_B**

```
OrderDetails_B_ID Pk int
OrderID Fk int
Qty_B
ItemDesc_B
```

Here is what I know doesn't work but what I would like to do.

```
SELECT O.OrderDate,O.OrderedByID,
CASE WHEN O.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NULL 
     THEN
     SELECT B.ItemDesc_B as ItemDesc,B.Qty_B as Qty
     ELSE
     SELECT A.ItemDesc_A as ItemDesc,A.Qty_A as Qty
     END
FROM Orders as O
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include any JOIN criteria in your example so I'll omit them from mine as well.

```
SELECT O.OrderDate,O.OrderedByID,
CASE WHEN O.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NULL THEN B.ItemDesc_B ELSE A.ItemDesc_A END as ItemDesc,
CASE WHEN O.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NULL THEN B.Qty_B ELSE A.Qty_A END as Qty
FROM Orders as O
```

Comment: No, but neither will his example. I assume he didn't include his JOIN criteria because he already knows how to do the join and wanted us to focus on just sorting the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could either coalesce or use an inner join with a union.

Using coalesce, you can control it per field.  Using union, you don't have to specify the exact columns over and over.

Coalesce:

```
select o.OrderID, COALESCE(a.Qty_A, a.Qty_B) as Qty
from Orders o
left outer join Order_Detail_A a on o.OrderID = a.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is not null
left outer join Order_Detail_B b on o.OrderID = b.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is null
```

Unions:

```
select o.OrderID, a.Qty_A as Qty
from Orders o
inner join Order_Detail_A a on o.OrderID = a.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is not null
union all
select o.OrderID, b.Qty_B as Qty
from Orders o
inner join Order_Detail_B b on o.OrderID = b.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is null
```

Comment: `coalesce` is actually wrong, will select `Qty_B` when `Qty_A` is joined and present, but is null.

Comment: Ok, I forgot one thing, If o.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NULL, I only want the first record entered from the OrderDetails_A table and if it IS NOT NULL than I want all records from OrderDetails_B. I would explain but my brain hurts enough trying to brownstone a legasy app.

Comment: @GSerg, as part of the join, both a and b cannot be present.  If OrderDetails_A_ID is not null, a can find a row, otherwise only b can find a row.

Comment: @AkAlan, then I would certainly go with the union.  Change the select for Order_Details_A to be 'SELECT TOP(1) o.OrderID, a.Qty_A as Qty' and you should get the result you are looking for.

Comment: I tried the Top(1) but it only returns one record total. I need all orders from Orders and only the top 1 Order_Detail_A if o.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NULL.

Comment: Mybad, I meant this: I need all orders from Orders and only the top 1 Order_Detail_A if o.OrderDetails_A_ID IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  o.OrderDate,
  o.OrderedByID,
  case when o.OrderDetails_A_ID is null then b.ItemDesc_B else a.ItemDesc_A end as ItemDesc,
  case when o.OrderDetails_A_ID is null then b.Qty_B else a.Qty_A end as Qty
FROM
  Orders as O 
  left join OrderDetails_A a on a.OrderID = o.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is not null
  left join OrderDetails_B b on b.OrderID = o.OrderID and o.OrderDetails_A_ID is null
```

Comment: I ended up with the following and it gives me exactly what I needed                                                        select h.headerid,h.dateordered,h.deliverylocation ,coalesce(poi.itemdata,L.orderdetail) as ordereditem from header as H Inner join (select * from (select l.* ,row_number() over (partition by headerid order by lineid) as rn from lineitem ) as x where rn=1 ) as L on h.headerid=l.headerid left outer join potable as PO on h.poid=po.poid left outer join poitem as poi on h.poid=poi.poid